# how to change bridge mode to normal mode

Tags: windows-xp

I have a dlink router. and my laptop connects to it via wifi but when i type in CMD ipconfig to find the default gateway which must be the router the address looks something like this:

ipv4 address: 192.168.43.249 subnet mask: 255.255.225.0 default gateway: 192.168.43.1

but when i enter the default gateway to my browser i cant access my router admin page? how can i find the right ip of my router if I have a public IP assigned by the ISP?

wireless-networking

Comment: I see three separate questions in here 1) the mode, 2) the internal address, 3) the external address. Could you decide which one is **the** question?

Comment: Often Dlink routers use 192.168.0.1 as their default login IP address. Which model Dlink? The public address really doesn't matter for the IP address used to log into your router, assuming you are logging in from a computer on the same internal network.

Answer (score 0):

Your default gateway (as communicated by the router to your computer by DHCP) is normally the ip-adddress of your router that you should use to get at the admin pages. This has nothing to do with whatever real ip-address your ISP assigns to the externally visibile ip-address of the router.

3 things come to mind:

1. You router doesn't use the default port 80 for it's webpage but another port. Check the manual of the router what link to enter in your browser. (E.g http://192.168.43.1:XX/ where XX is the correct portnumber. Please note that most browsers insist you explicitly add http:// in front of the ip-address if it is any other port than the default port 80.)
2. Your router has a setting that only allows the web-interface to be entered by any of it's normal LAN ports, not via Wifi. So try to connect your computer with a network cable to it and see if that helps.
3. Your router has actually 2 wifi LAN's. One for personal use and one for guests. You are connecting to the guest Wifi and access to the admin-page is forbidden for guests. Try to connect to the normal wifi or the use a wired port in stead.